# How can I fix old javascript to validate an international phone number with jQuery Validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I found [a blog post](http://www.24hourapps.com/2009/02/jquery-international-phone-number.html) which shows a method of creating validation for an international phone number. The code supplied is:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('intlphone', function(value) { return (value.match(/^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(\s*(ext|x)\s*\.?:?\s*([0-9]+))?$/)); }, 'Please enter a valid phone number');
```

I believe it used to work for me but something has changed - possibly a newer version of jQuery - and I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^((+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-s.])?(((d{1,4}))|d{1,4})(([-s.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(s*(ext|x)s*.?:?s*([0-9]+))?$/: Nothing to repeat
```

I created a JSBin with the items i'm working with, but I'm not having any luck getting rid of the error.

How can I fix old javascript to validate an international phone number with jQuery Validate?

ps: I believe I've tried running this with previous versions of jQuery and I'm still getting the error. I'm not sure what changed.

Ended up using this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('intlphone', function(value) { return (value.match(/^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([\-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([\-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(\s*(ext|x)\s*\.?:?\s*([0-9]+))?$/)); }, 'Please enter a valid phone number');
```

Comment: It has a couple unescaped `-` maybe that's the problem. Try with: `/^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([\-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([\-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(\s*(ext|x)\s*\.?:?\s*([0-9]+))?$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

It will be a lot easier to strip the non-digit characters and create a regex to match only the numbers and extension.

Add this to the beginning of your function to remove all non-digits other than x:
`value.replace("[^\d+x]", "").match` ....